# Is it possible to customize the display template of the hover panel that appear in searches from SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to customize the display template of the hover panel that appear in searches from SharePoint Online ?

If applicable, may you share some guidance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As spguy pointed out, that's informative article you can refer to make modifications.

You need not even have SharePoint Designer to do this, you can simply use NotePad++ to customise the Display templates.

Copy the existing Item Template HTML file Modify it upload it. When you upload HTML file a JS file with same name would be automatically created.

The article correctly pointed as below

- Each result type contains a reference to an item display template.
- Each item display template contains a reference to a hover panel display template.
- Each item display template contains a reference to the common item
  display template.
- Each referenced hover panel display template contains references to
  three common hover panel display templates.

**Item Template** provides HTML that determines how each item in the result set is displayed. For example, the Item Display Template might provide the HTML for a list item that contains a picture, three lines of text that are mapped to different managed properties associated with the item. The Item Display Template is rendered one time for each item in the result set. So, if the result set contains ten items, the Item Display Template creates its section of HTML ten times.

Under Content Web Parts Library there are several file names starting with "Control_" and "Item_", files starting with Control are Control Templates and files starting with Item are Item templates. Also there are two file extensions for each file type .html and .js.

**.js is strictly for SharePoint internal use and not to be changed by users.**

Referece:
[Modify Hover Panel](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/09/12/how-to-display-values-from-custom-managed-properties-in-the-hover-panel-in-sharepoint-server-2013/)

[Introduction to Display Templates](http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2013-display-templates/)

[How to Add custom Actions on Hover Panel](https://www.eliostruyf.com/adding-customizing-actions-search-hover-panel/)

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Refer to this Microsoft SharePoint blog post as it provides step-by-step directions to do this.

As described, start off by making a copy of an existing hover panel via SharePoint Designer provided OOTB. From there, you can make your changes.

[How to display values from custom managed properties in the hover panel in SharePoint Server 2013](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/09/12/how-to-display-values-from-custom-managed-properties-in-the-hover-panel-in-sharepoint-server-2013/)

Comment: If you find that my answer has addressed your question, please be sure to mark it as the answer.

Comment: when you make answers you can copy in key points to the answers rather than giving the links directly, that will help other users  who might not look into details might get benefit too and when the reference links might get update /not available- important points in this answers will stay relevant to community members