# Hover panel in content search webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online

[image]

I have designed a six lines showing content search webpart. However I am not been able to get the hover panel.
I have used to following code for hover:

```
var id = ctx.ClientControl.get_nextUniqueId();
var itemId = id + Srch.U.Ids.item;
var hoverId = id + Srch.U.Ids.hover;
var hoverUrl = "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_Site_HoverPanel.js";
$setResultItem(itemId, ctx.CurrentItem);
ctx.currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getShowHoverPanelCallback(itemId, hoverId, hoverUrl);
ctx.currentItem_HideHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getHideHoverPanelCallback();

<div class="cbs-Item" id="_#= $htmlEncode(itemId) =#_" onmouseover="_#= ctx.currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback =#_" onmouseout="_#= ctx.currentItem_HideHoverPanelCallback =#_">    

<div id="_#= $htmlEncode(hoverId) =#_" class="ms-srch-hover-outerContainer"></div>
```

But i am getting error "We didn't find any more information about this result".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy an existing hover panel via SharePoint Designer provided OOTB.

From there, you can make your changes.

You can refer to the following situation:

[Is it possible to customize the display template of the hover panel that appear in searches from SharePoint Online?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/181279/is-it-possible-to-customize-the-display-template-of-the-hover-panel-that-appear)

[How to display values from custom managed properties in the hover panel in SharePoint Server 2013](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/09/12/how-to-display-values-from-custom-managed-properties-in-the-hover-panel-in-sharepoint-server-2013/)

[Adding a hover panel to a content search webpart display template.](http://yeshagrawal.blogspot.com/2013/06/sharepoint-2013-search-adding-hover.html)

Comment: The code you have suggested is similar to mine but the results are not coming up.